# OR condition in Excel Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot

In pivots, by keeping columns in filter section and applying conditions on them, Conditions are used as "AND" operator. 
For example, suppose I have 2 columns on filter section - Age and Gender. I applied condition on Age as age < 30 and gender = male. Data will get filtered and will show only those values which have age > 30 AND male.

I want to apply OR condition in Excel pivot i.e. by applying above condition, data should get filtered and show values for age > 30 OR Gender = Male. So Female data should also come for age > 30 population.
Can you help me on how to get above results i.e. how to apply OR condition in pivot?

Answer (score 0):

If using 'traditional' pivots, you need to use *two* PivotTables: one for one condition, and one for the other. Then sum the two results together. The GETPIVOTDATA function can be handy here.

If you have Excel 2013 or later, you have a much better option: you can add the data to the DataModel and then write your own custom measures using the DAX language. This is easiest if you have a 'Premium' version that ships with the PowerPivot functionality, an PowerPivot is the 'UI' for using the data model. But you can actually still write DAX measures without PowerPivot installed, as outlined at the following link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVVK-8QZC1M

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to define the complex conditions in an additional helper column before you create the pivot table.

That is, add a column to the source data with `or(age > 30, Gender = Male)`. Include that column as a filter in the pivot table.

Not very flexible from an end-user interaction point of view since you need to know the condition before hand. But it works.